# Could edits to answers be indicated without having to refresh

Tags: discussion, feature-request, live-refresh

When viewing a question I found an answer that could be improved. I clicked on edit and was presented with what I would have edited it to.

Could there be some way of letting me know there's been an edit without me having to refresh the page?

---

<sup>Possibly other things could be refreshed too like # of question close votes and whether it's closed (which is particularly useful when writing an answer only to have the "Question is closed" troll turn up).</sup>

Comment: I agree with letting one see that there _has been_ and edit, but _please_ don't auto-load the newly edited content.

Comment: @cdeszaq: I guess it could get annoying for large edits that cause content to jump about - edited.